# Bitmap Fonts for Retina Display

Tags: objective-c, ios, fonts, cocos2d-iphone

Right now, I have a couple fonts: HoboStd20.fnt which points to HoboStd20.png and Teen40.fnt which points to Teen40.png

However, I need retina display fonts.
How do I go about inserting these bitmap fonts into the app?
Do I need to create a font that is twice the size of the original fonts?
How should I name the fonts? Do I rename both the png and fnt file like this: HoboStd20-hd.fnt?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic routine is to design your bitmap font at either SD or HD resolution. Then re-export the same font with double or half the font size.

For example, when I design fonts using Glyph Designer (highly recommended), I first create the Retina font and save it as font-hd.fnt. Let's say this has a font size of 40 points. Next I set the font size to 20, and re-export the file as font.fnt.

In cocos2d you reference only the font.fnt file. It will automatically load the font-hd.fnt file on Retina devices.

Comment: Thank you! ^_^ By the way, I read your book and found it EXTREMELY helpful! I would say, your book helped set me off in the direction of game creation with Cocos2D! Again, thanks for your easy to understand explanations, which I appreciate greatly!

Comment: In Cocos Creator it seems it works the same way but with ~~hs suffix (https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/question-about-bitmap-font-in-retina-mode/160/4?u=balazsnemeth)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using [Angelcode's BMFont](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/) to generate the fonts (are you?).

Are you using alpha-tested edges for these fonts or using a [distance-field](http://bitsquid.blogspot.com/2010/04/distance-field-based-rendering-of.html) based rendering scheme?

[This](http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf) paper called "Alpha-Tested Magniﬁcation for Vector Textures and Special Effects" might help you get acceptable quality without having to double the size of the font/texture.

That said, if you are using BMFont (and can write shaders to unpack pixel data) - it is also possible to pack multiple pages using one bit per page or one channel per page. This + alpha tested + distance field should give you pixel-perfect quality for text.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! unfortunately, this is not exactly what I need.